# Reboot when required - c# and Windows Update

Tags: c#, windows, api, console, windows-update

I'm building a c# console application that automatically finds updates, downloads them and installs them.

I'm using this method for the installation part:

```
        public static void InstallUpdates(UpdateCollection DownloadedUpdates)
    {
        UpdateSession UpdateSession = new UpdateSession();
        UpdateInstaller InstallAgent = UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller() as UpdateInstaller;
        InstallAgent.Updates = DownloadedUpdates;

        //Starts a synchronous installation of the updates.
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386491(v=VS.85).aspx#methods
        IInstallationResult InstallResult = InstallAgent.Install();

    }
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386491(v=VS.85).aspx#properties) link, I can check whether or not a reboot is required. What I want to achieve is a system reboot that is done immediately when the RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation changes to true.

I thought of doing this, but that won't work because I can't use an else statement:

```
        while (!InstallAgent.RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation)
        {

        } else
        {
            // Reboot
        }
```

What would be the correct approach to this?

Comment: Why can't you use an `if-else` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: @xxbbcc at first I thought that an if-else statement would run at once and not after a while - but the more I think about it the more I realise that that line isn't called before the installation is done. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
while (!InstallAgent.RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation)
{
    // Install things
    // If the installer sets the RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation flag to
    // true, the while loop will terminate and you can reboot.
}

if (InstallAgent.RebootRequiredBeforeInstallation)
{
    // Reboot
}
```

Comment: I did some logging now and it seems the code after IInstallationResult InstallResult = InstallAgent.Install(); isn't ran before the installation is done. So I guess an if-else statement would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Erik Yes, it should. _Synchronous_ installation is exactly that - you call the installer to perform an installation and your code waits until the installer either completes or fails before your program can continue.

Comment: I understand. Do you know a lot about Windows Update related code? I've got a few problems with exceptions here that I really need some help with, but I can't post before tomorrow. Getting late here

Comment: @Erik No, I've never used it before. :)  But post your problems as individual questions and you'll likely get help. Just make sure you post detailed questions so people can understand what you're trying to do and what goes wrong.

Comment: sure thing, I've got good impression from this site so I guess that won't be a problem:) Thanks for your help!